# Groovy, collect objects following a property while not null?

Tags: groovy

Is there already a way in groovy to collect objects following a property while not null ?

```
Object.metaClass {
    collectWhileNotNull = { Closure follow ->
        def result = []

        def previous = null
        for (def current = delegate; !current.is(previous) && (current != null); current = follow(current)){
            result << current
            previous = current
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

It is useful for recursive data structure.

An example of usage for a groovy.util.Node :

```
Closure getAncestors = { Node n -> n.collectWhileNotNull{ it.parent() }.tail().reverse() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Generator` class (this is also the name of the necessary pattern) from [cookbook](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Iterator+Tricks).

Comment: Maybe we can use Stream : http://blog.bloidonia.com/post/41103158982/lazy-squares-using-groovy-stream

Comment: Wow, that deserves an accepted answer. And a cookbook entry. And an inclusion into core Groovy.